# How to use "distinct" RxJS operator in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, rxjs5

Below is my Angular 2 component code

```
import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinct';

@Component({
             selector:'js',
             template: `
                       <input type="text" id="txt" value="">                           `
          })


  export class Js1Component implements OnInit{  

      ngOnInit(){   

         var data = Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('txt'),'keypress')
        .distinct()
        .subscribe({
            next: (e) => { console.log(e);}
        });

   }
}
```

Since I am using "distinct" operator , when user types "Hello" in textbox , I 
was expecting that only character h , e , l and o will be printed in the console,that is only one "l" will be printed.
But instead all the character are printed( h e l l o).

Any idea how the distinct operator needs to be used.

Comment: `e` is an object, not a string. Of course it will be different every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by @estus in the comment, `e` is an object in your example and not a string. Hence it's different every time (even if the object's keys were all the same, the reference is different).

You can `map` the event you receive into the pressed key with function `event => event.key`.

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'keypress')
  .map(event => event.key)
  .distinct()
  .subscribe(e => console.log(e)); // logs key pressed
```

Depending on the use case, you might need the whole event, and not just the letter pressed afterwards. In that case, using the map operator is a bad idea since you lose all other information.

If this is the case, you can supply a function to `.distinct` operator. By default this is an identity mapping `x => x`, but you can make it `event => event.key`. It will then consider items in the stream different if their `.key` properties are different.

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'keypress')
  .distinct(event => event.key)
  .subscribe(e => console.log(e)); // logs whole event (distinct keys)
```

On the side note, notice how I don't use native DOM API (like `getElementById`). You should use `@ViewChild` decorator instead for grabbing elements from the template. [The full **Plunker** is here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/f8dGyHdx1SUcpJNOcnjo?p=preview)